# Open new chrome window on monitor my mouse is currently in, OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I have two monitors. If I'm using Chrome on both monitors (two windows), and I close the window on monitor A, focus changes to monitor B. Then, when I open a new tab using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, the window opens on monitor B.

I want to open a window on the monitor my mouse is currently on (A), not the one the currently-open window is on (B), without using the mouse.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Try using CMD+N to open a new window. I'm under the assumption that if Chrome is still in focus (in the menu bar of that particular desktop) then you can use that command to open a new window after you dismissed the last tab.

Comment: Yes, but does it open on the monitor where the mouse is?

Comment: This will open a new window, but on the wrong monitor (opens where the open window is, not where the mouse is).

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood. I didn't see that it had already changed focus.